# why main() return value does not set exitcode in dart?

Tags: dart

Dart is suppose to be pragmatic, intuitive, etc.
I wonder Why top-level main() does not set exitcode if int is returned?

I know, you can set it via `dart:io.exitCode=` or use `dart:io.exit()`.

The question is **why language designers decided to drop such popular convention**?

```dart
#!/path/to/dart --checked
int main() {
  int myExitCode = 5;
  return myExitCode;
}
```

It returns 0 (as described in [documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#functions)), but in command-line world it's just silly.
It does not even warn you (compiler checked mode, dartanalyzer). Script just silently return 0. Is there any rationale behind it?

**UPDATE:**

proposal bug: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21639

Answer (score 10):

The `main()` method in Dart always returns void, even if you specify otherwise. See [The main() function](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#the-main-function) As mentioned in the answer from John Evans, you must use the exit function if you want to return a value. This is because the Dart VM runs in both CLI and in a browser. It makes no sense in terms of the browser to provide a return value from main(). Thus the functionality is limited to the `dart:io` library which will only run in the CLI version of the dart VM.

Comment: I know what documentation says about main(). Once again, the question is why such behavior? Why not at least warning? It's misleading.

Comment: Agreed. There should be a warning, or at least at hint in the editor that main return type must be void (if provided at all) and a warning/hint on a return statement in main that provides anything other than null. I suggest filing a bug at: http://dartbug.com

Answer (score 8):

My understanding for this is that while `main()` may finish executing, you might have other asynchronous work going on that hasn't completed yet.  You can use `exit` from the `dart:io` lib to return a exit code immediately.

```
import 'dart:io';

 main(){
    exit(42);
 }
```

More info from the API docs about exit: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io#id_exit

Comment: I know that. I just expect dart to call `dart:io.exitCode=` with value returned by main if it's `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer would be that returning value from `main()` will not make sense in browser (as Matt B pointed out, +1), so dart does not let it at all.

But this is incoherent, since getting list of commandline arguments `main(List<String> args)` does not make sense in a browser environment either, and dart languages supports `main(List<String> args)`.

On the other hand, support for main-return-sets-exitCode feature would tight heart of dart 
(how top-level main() is treated) to `dart:io` which is not available in browsers.
However, I personally don't think it wouldn't be that bad as having such wired and unexpected behavior as shown in the question's code.